# How to have images in one line going all the way across the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i am having a problem i have a list of images that are in a div which is in another div with a class of streaming. i want the images to be side by side in a line and i want the div with the class of streaming to have a scroll bar at the bottom of the div so when i scroll i see the images i want to scroll horizontally not vertically i want the vertical scroll bar to not show. but i am having problems with that this problem is really testing my patience. I tried doing float:left on the divs that were in side of the div with the class streaming but it just stacks them when it gets to the edge of the page, I also need it to adjust if more items are added. Thank You

HTML:

```
<div class="streaming">
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
    <div><img src="../img/ben.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.streaming div {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}

.streaming {
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with `flex`, and a default flex `row` will behave this way.

```css
.streaming div {
  padding: 5px;
}

.streaming {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="streaming">
    <div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div><div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
  <div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
  <div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
  <div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
  <div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
  <div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
  <div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
  <div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
  <div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div><div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
  <div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
  <div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
  <div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
  <div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
  <div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
  <div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
  <div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" height="60"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i will try this

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to set `overflow-y:hidden` to the streaming div. I would not use float but instead would do this:

```css
.streaming > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 49%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding display: inline; to your div css

```
.streaming > div {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: this worked but it was quite what i was looking for thank you though